# Adding fields to NFT metadata

Tags: nearprotocol

If I'll add some fields to NFT metadata, minted on the NEAR blockchain, will it be still NEP 171 compatible? If not, what is the right way to do that? Is it right to put JSON under the `extra` field in NFT metadata?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can definitely add fields to the NFT metadata. It will conform to the standard as long as you have the required fields found in the metadata [standard](https://nomicon.io/Standards/NonFungibleToken/Metadata.html).